# How can I use the JXD S7300 game controller with RetroArch?

Tags: usb-peripherals, emulators, game-controllers

I want to use my JXD S7300 controllers with the Android [RetroArch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.retroarch) game emulator. But It seems not to be possible. Anyone has info?

Comment: Ok I think that I've fixed this deficiencies of info. The app support so many controller devices but the JXD S7300 is like a PSP, have buttons and joysticks and I don't know how to configure it, I think that is not possible

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to improve the quality and removed my downvote. Please also add the info why the controller is not working: Is it not detected by Android? Or by RetroArch? etc.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved it!!!

It's easy when you see someone using this tablet.
In this video, [JDX S7300 testing with ShadowGun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqrRQOI9sZY), you can see how to set the controls in the 1:30